# Python pandas plotting error when both 'color' and 'style' arguments are passed

Tags: pandas

In pandas, when using the plot method and passing both arguments 'color' and 'style', there is an error which I think should be raised only when there is a color symbol in the style string. But in the example below, the error is raised even though there is no color symbol in the style string:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
df = DataFrame({'a': np.random.rand(10), 'b': np.random.rand(10), 'c': np.random.rand(10)})
df.plot(color = ['red', 'black', 'blue'], style = ['-', '--', '-'])
```

The error is not clear (TypeError: expected string or buffer). This should be fixed, although it is easy to work around:

```
df.plot(style = ['r-', 'k--', 'b-'])
```

Comment: This looks like a bug to me too, can you post your pandas version, mine is `0.15.2`, could you post a bug report to [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues)

Comment: My pandas version is `0.15.2` too. I posted a bug report here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9671

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in pandas v0.16.1